# Installation of Action Pack Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 stuck at ~70%

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, microsoft-office

In fresh installations of Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (fully patched) and Windows 10 Professional 64-bit, the installation of the Action Pack version of Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 32-bit is getting stuck on ~70 % (progress = 478 px, progress bar = 656 px).

I thought there was something wrong with my installation media so, on 2016/08/25, I logged into the Microsoft Partner / Action Pack portal, downloaded and extracted file "SW_DVD5_Office_Professional_Plus_2016_32_BIT_X64_English_C2R_X20-30528.ISO" (SHA-1 checksum / hash `F6FE715A45B0C31D537A3213256E81527171A9EA`), and tried again but to no avail.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

I haven't been able to find anything on the web for this, hence this post.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: How long did you leave it "stuck", before giving up?  When it's stuck is the HDD and/or CPU busy?

Comment: Since you gave no system specs we can only guess, sometimes you have to let it run overnight, be patient.

Comment: Your screenshots are not really of anything helpful.  Only the last one provides any significant information.  Pictures of the installer before the problem happens, and the folder where the installer was saved too, are tell us very little if anything

Comment: Fine, I have removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An updated installer has been released (ISO file MD5 hash `400822373C99182A558DC4EA4CC7F700`) which resolved the problem.